# Lambda expression Linq-to-SQL get from record 5 to 10

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq, lambda

I have been trying to get the following:

I have a table with 20 elements in it. I'm trying to write a method that gets a number of records, with some kind of an offset.

For example: I would like to get 5 elements, starting from the 6th one... which means I'd like to have record nr 6,7,8,9 and 10.

Those numbers are not a column or id in the table! I would like to sort the table in a specific way with the result id's get shuffled.

This is my query so far:

```
project1_category[] categories = db.project1_categories.Select(c => c)
                                                       .OrderBy(c => c.Category)
                                                       .ToArray();
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As a side note, `Select(c => c)` is redundant and actually does nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `Skip` and `Take`:

```
project1_category[] categories = db.project1_categories.OrderBy(c => c.Category)
                                                       .Skip(5)
                                                       .Take(5)
                                                       .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `Skip`

[Enumerable.Skip Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx)

and `Take`

[Enumerable.Take Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx)

```
var categories = db.project1_categories.Select(c => c).
    OrderBy(c => c.Category).Skip(5).Take(5).ToArray();
```